# Wireless connection active but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a Asus F555LA-AB31 laptop. I can access the internet just fine on my home wireless network, however I can't seem to connect to the internet on the wireless network at work, even though there appears to be an active connection to the wireless network.

I've tried many of the suggestions given for similar previous questions, including setting DNS to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, ignoring IPv6, and forgetting the network--none have done the trick.

Results of some diagnostics:

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:5c:8e:2f:c0:31  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:1023784 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1023784 (1.0 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:c0:90:4b:1f:ee  
      inet addr:172.20.141.97  Bcast:172.20.143.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::167c:c0c:8b7a:fef9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:42471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:39907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:41127385 (41.1 MB)  TX bytes:6440187 (6.4 MB)


$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.143.254  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
1.1.1.1         172.20.143.254  255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
172.20.140.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0



$ ping -c10 google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? I've read that the wireless card shipped with this Asus laptop is not truly linux compatible, but I'm not sure if that could be the issue if I can access the internet on a different wireless network without any difficulties. Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
$ ping -c10 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9072ms
```

Comment: Might want to swing by the IT department and see if they have any funky stuff set up on the network.

Comment: Please ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks, I might try going by IT if I can't solve it, although on the phone I was told they don't support linux so I'm not sure how helpful they'll be. I've added the ping 8.8.8.8 in an edit above.